# Jquery Tooltip not Showing First Time mouseover

Tags: jquery, tooltip, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to show a tooltip in a button but it's only showing on the first time hover. The code is as follows,

```
$('.navbar-btn').mouseover(function() {
        $(this).tooltip({
            trigger: 'hover',
            delay: {
                show: 200
            },
            title : $(this).text()
        }); 
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Tooltip - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( document ).tooltip();
  } );
  </script>
  <style>
  label {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 5em;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
 

<p><label for="age">Your age:</label><input id="age" title="We ask for your age only for statistical purposes."></p>
<p>Hover the field to see the tooltip.</p>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

```
$( document ).tooltip();
```

refer this link:

https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/ 
Try this link answer will be their

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a mouse over function. simply attach the tooltip on the button.

```
$('.navbar-btn').tooltip({
  items: "button",
  content: ".",
  open: function() {
    $(this).tooltip( "option", "content", $(this).text() );
  }
});
```